# Get data from MySQL between string integer data type

Tags: mysql, between

I want to get data for sum(cost) in from date and to date. my table fields data type is id is INT AUTO INCREMENT, dd is varchar, mm is varchar, yyyy varchar and dd value is 01 to 31, mm value is 01 to 12 and year value is 4 digit year(2016 or 2015...,)
I want exactly sum(cost) = 143

```
SELECT SUM(cost) FROM costing
WHERE 
    (( dd> CAST('05' AS SIGNED) AND mm= CAST('12' AS SIGNED) AND yyyy= CAST('2015' AS SIGNED))
  AND
    ((dd<= CAST('23' AS SIGNED) AND mm = CAST('01' AS SIGNED) AND yyyy= CAST('2016' AS SIGNED)))

  order by id
```

[image]

Comment: This seems awfully complicated. Why not have a `DATE` field and do a much simpler `BETWEEN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CAST AS DATE function like this:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(cost) FROM costing
WHERE
     CAST(CONCAT(yyyy,mm,dd) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-12-05' AND '2016-01-23'
```

Comment: Thanks @selvinsource

Comment: If i first time report generation i dont know from date that means 2015-12-05. I i run 5th dec 2015 i need before all data's sum

Answer (score 1):

First you should consider about your data types. Dates should not in varchar or integer data types. refer this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Then you can use between. refer this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Then you no need `order by id` in your query.

Your query will like 
`SELECT SUM(cost) FROM costing WHERE costingdate BETWEEN "5-12-2015" AND 23-1-2015"`